# An appropriate way to seek suicide resources (as an author)

Tags: character-development, resources

I'm doing the analysis for several characters who happen to be contemplating taking their own lives.  While I'm not someone interested in this myself, I'd like to seek resources **without wasting the time of critical professionals and certainly without interfering with or exhausting people who might find themselves in this category**:  I am *not* writing a documentary, I'm writing a novel.

There are blogs, etc but are there any quintessential resources *directly related to author sensitivities, language usage, and so on* - without interfering with any real-life subjects? e.g., I don't want to interview someone; this is fiction, I just want to know the correct language.

Comment: You can look at specific **critiques** of suicide-related programs and books (*13 reasons,* eg caught some flak) and compile a list of 'what not to do.' You can find other such programs and books that have been recognized for their appropriate treatment of the subject and use that as a 'good' guide. E.g.  https://fivebooks.com/best-books/suicide-johanna-reiss/ If you plan to publish traditionally, you can ask for a sensitivity reader.

Comment: There are tons of online resources about suicide, all aimed at different sets of people (different ages, genders, sexual orientations, professions, ethnicity, etc).  Plus if you go to your local library you'll find a big shelf full of books.  There are often drop-in centers or, more often, general community resource centers with brochures and etc.  If there's no one else there, you can chat with the staff if they're up for it.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Clinical cases, support material for people contemplating suicide, some aspects of the psychology of self-harm?

Comment: @NofP - The contemplation and completion of the suicides happen early on and I'm not too worried about the dialogue of the young people.  Handling the narrative (as the author) in this fiction, I want to be updated in 2019 sensitivities in language, et al.  The intended audience is young adult and adults and dealing with the grief is a sidebar to the overall narrative.  I love all of the comments so far, thanks!

Comment: I answered this question here: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/why-do-people-commit-suicide

Comment: @BustyNurse - I do not see your answer there.

Comment: @DPT That should be an answer, it's a good one. See [this meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1873/33442)

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/Suicide Is a good work for not only discussing a lay perspective on topics of suicide, but is written specifically for fiction writers looking to portray just about anything... the useful notes articles being specifically geared to factual matters of the topic that often get missed in a media portrayal.  It's more a resource for what to consider in the story.   Please note this is not vetted by anyone remotely claiming to be an expert, so be sure to follow up with other resources for research.  Also it's TVTropes.  You have been warned.

Answer (score 6):

I would start with the literature produced by suicide prevention programs.

Its targeting the minds of people considering suicide and its trying to educate people of the warning signs, and how to help.  This will provide you with insight into the mental frame of your characters

Then, you can access research materials produced by psychologists and social workers studying this field.  You can find their work at your local university.  If that isn’t convenient, then you can use google books to access past publications.  I found this [journal](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=swbMhfC2D3AC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=suicide%20research&ots=o7xJg1GYqu&sig=cWajzei_H4gIPfAmhmg1Uoc3HlU#v=onepage&q=suicide%20research&f=false) in only a few minutes searching

Comment: Welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] for the usual badges and visit the [help] for additional guidance. This is a great first answer. Thanks for contributing and happy writing!